# Como saber si una fecha se pasa de dos meses en JS

Tags: javascript, date

Buenas tengo dos fechas en tipo string como pueden ser las siguientes:

```
var fecha1 = '2018-11-03';
var fecha2 = '2018-02-03';
```

Y quiero saber cual es el código más eficiente para comparar esas dos fechas y saber si la diferencia de meses es 2 o superior.

Edito: Tengo un formulario con bootstrap y si me lo indicáis el código de la validación mejor que mejor, por ahora sólo tengo lo siguiente en esa validación:

```
fecha: {
                validators:{
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'Seleccione una fecha valida'
                    }
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para comparar 2 fechas, únicamente has de convertir estas a tipo `Date`para ello te indico un ejemplo:

```js
/**
 * Compara 2 numeros indicando si el primero es menor o igual que el segundo
 */
const lte = (n1, n2) => {
  return n1 <= n2;
}

/**
 * Niega un objeto
 */
const not = (o1) => !o1;

/**
 * Obtiene la diferencia en meses de 2 fechas
 */
const diffBetweenMonths = (dateFrom, dateTo) => {
  if(not(dateFrom instanceof Date)) dateFrom = new Date(dateFrom);
  if(not(dateTo instanceof Date)) dateTo = new Date(dateTo);
  
  let months = 0;
  
  months = (dateFrom.getFullYear() - dateTo.getFullYear()) * 12;
  months -= dateTo.getMonth() + 1;
  months += dateFrom.getMonth();
  
  return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
};

var fecha1 = '2018-11-03';
var fecha2 = '2017-11-03';

if(not(lte(diffBetweenMonths(fecha1, fecha2), 2))) { 
  console.log('Fecha superior a 2 meses');
}

var fecha1 = '2018-04-03';
var fecha2 = '2018-02-03';

if(lte(diffBetweenMonths(fecha1, fecha2), 2)) { 
  console.log('Fecha no superior a 2 meses');
}
```

La función `diffBetweenMonths` castea los parámetros a Date si son de otro tipo y luego utiliza la función `getMonth()`, la cual retorna el mes menos 1 (en vez de 11 retorna 10) obteniendo el valor de los meses y pudiendo restar el mes desde (se supone que será mayor) contra el mes from (que se supone que será menor).

Answer (score 6):

Que tal si restamos los dos meses a la fecha 1 y la comparamos a la fecha 2?? mira el ejemplo sin usar librerias externas solo usando [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)

```js
var fecha1 = '2018-04-03';
var fecha2 = '2018-02-03';

const fecha_compare_1 = new Date(fecha1)
const fecha_compare_2 = new Date(fecha2)

fecha_compare_1.setMonth(fecha_compare_1.getMonth()- 2);

console.log(`fecha1 es mayor a dos meses? > ${fecha_compare_1> fecha_compare_2} `  )
```

> Lo unico que debes tener cuidado es que la fecha empiezan desde
>   cero(0), es decir Enero es el mes cero